# applying Microsoft configuration transformations from a command line?

Tags: .net, configuration

From this article I see I can use msbuild to apply configuration transformations but is there another way using either a command line program or.Net API?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/gg454290

Update:

I found an answer:

http://mbonig.wordpress.com/2012/01/11/using-the-vs2010-publishing-configuration-transformations-outside-of-vs2010/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer on this and provided a quick writeup on it:

http://mbonig.wordpress.com/2012/01/11/using-the-vs2010-publishing-configuration-transformations-outside-of-vs2010/